# Python3 compose HTTP GET message

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, networking, get

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET message to a server through a TCP connection, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server, port))

message = 'GET /' + direction + ' HTTP/1.1'    

s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    webpage = s.recv(1024)

    print(webpage)

    if not webpage:
        break

    with open('step3.txt', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(webpage.decode('utf-8').content)
```

The important thing here is the composition of variable `message`, because the problem is that server does not recognize the HTTP request message apparently.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not user higher level libraries such as `http.client` or `requests`?

Comment: The thing is that this exercise is for not using those libraries haha

Comment: Eh, why work harder and not smarter? Their underlying code uses `socket`.

Comment: I know, but it is not my election :). Teachers' stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the server is refusing your HTTP request because your request body isn't valid. Take a look at this valid request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.test.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
(empty line)
```

First thing: **your request must end with an empty line (`\r\n`)**. In your context, that means `message = 'GET /' + direction + ' HTTP/1.1\n'`.

Then, there are some missing headers:

- The [`Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) is **required** in valid HTTP requests.
- The [`User-Agent` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) is optional but most servers require it.

Take a shot using something like this, replacing `www.test.com` by the actual hostname you want to communicate with:

```
message = ''
message += 'GET /' + direction + ' HTTP/1.1\r\n'
message += 'Host: www.test.com\r\n'
message += 'User-Agent: my agent\r\n'
message += '\r\n'
```

Finally, unless you are required to write use `socket`, I recommend using either [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html). These packages encapsulate the hard-work behind dealing with TCP/UDP sockets by hand.

Comment: @t.m.adam You're right. I just updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much @matheus-portela. That was the correct option to make an HTTP request!!